# Coloured Bullets NSTextList

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am using a NSTextList in a text editor I am building. I am trying to change the colour of the bullets in NSTextList while still keeping the built in functionality of an NSTextList. So far I have tried overriding the [shouldChangeText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449532-shouldchangetext) function in NSTextList to intercept when a bullet is being added and tried to replace it with my own coloured bullet.

```
override func shouldChangeText(in affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String) {
    if replacementString == "\t\u{2022}\t" {
        let redBullet = NSAttributedString(string: "\t\u{2022}\t", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.red])
        insertText(redBullet, replacementRange: affectedCharRange)
        return false
    }
}
```

However, this does not keep the functionality of a NSTextList and does not distinguish whether the bullet is already coloured or not. Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.